# How can I determine the right and most efficient DTU setting for an Azure SQL Server?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm looking to get the dtu for an Azure SQL database over a period of time , let's say a 6 month period, so that I can see where the database peaked to make a informed decision as what to set my DTU for the database.

Or how do I determine what to set my DTU for a database? The issue is that I can set it at 400, that costs quite a bit, but in reality all I need is 100.

I have set most to 400 but I think this is way too much. This is not a nominal value for all servers. How can I determine what to set it at?
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can view your DTU usage by navigating to the `Metrics` blade on your SQL database, and set a custom timeframe to look at historical data.

[image: DTU percentage metric]

Historical data is available based on the retention period you have configured in the log analytics workspace (LAW) you have linked with your SQL database. To determine what LAW is linked, navigate to the `Diagnostic settings` blade (under `Metrics`).

Here, you can navigate to the `Usage and estimated costs` blade to view/update your retention settings:

[image]

I am hesitant to recommend to recommend on how do you determine how many DTU's to choose, as this depends on your use case, and how much wiggle room you require.